# Sed or awk - need to grab a substring and append it to the end of the line

Tags: windows, text, sed, awk, substring

I am using Windows sed / awk but unix commands are similar,

file1

```
\\FILE09\12GAGE\LOAN CLOSING UNIT;\\FILE09\12GAGE;/fs8_100X/FILE09/bu/12gage
\\FILE44\FILE44\BU\EARPS\FUNDCHECK;\\FILE44\FILE44;/fs6_451B/FILE44
\\FILE15\FILE15\BU\MICROSOFT MACRO REMEDIATION;\\FILE15\FILE15;/fs6_100X/FILE15
```

Required output:

```
\\FILE09\12GAGE\LOAN CLOSING UNIT;\\FILE09\12GAGE;/fs8_100X/FILE09/bu/12gage/LOAN CLOSING UNIT
\\FILE44\FILE44\BU\EARPS\FUNDCHECK;\\FILE44\FILE44;/fs6_451B/FILE44/BU/EARPS/FUNDCHECK
\\FILE15\FILE15\BU\MICROSOFT MACRO REMEDIATION;\\FILE15\FILE15;/fs6_100X/FILE15/BU/MICROSOFT MACRO REMEDIATION
```

I need to grab the first field, grab the string after the 4th ocurrence of a backslack for example:

```
\\FILE44\FILE44\BU\EARPS\FUNDCHECK
```

It is going to be \BU\EARPS\FUNDCHECK, then convert backslash to slash: /BU/EARPS/FUNDCHECK
And then append that to the end of that line.

```
\\FILE44\FILE44\BU\EARPS\FUNDCHECK;\\FILE44\FILE44;/fs6_451B/FILE44/BU/EARPS/FUNDCHECK
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this one-liner may work:

```
 awk -F';' '{x=$1;sub(/\\\\[^\\]+\\[^\\]+\\/,"",x);gsub(/\\/,"/",x);print $0"/"x}' file
```

test

```
kent$  awk -F';' '{x=$1;sub(/\\\\[^\\]+\\[^\\]+\\/,"",x);gsub(/\\/,"/",x);print $0"/"x}' test
\\FILE09\12GAGE\LOAN CLOSING UNIT;\\FILE09\12GAGE;/fs8_100X/FILE09/bu/12gage/LOAN CLOSING UNIT
\\FILE44\FILE44\BU\EARPS\FUNDCHECK;\\FILE44\FILE44;/fs6_451B/FILE44/BU/EARPS/FUNDCHECK
\\FILE15\FILE15\BU\MICROSOFT MACRO REMEDIATION;\\FILE15\FILE15;/fs6_100X/FILE15/BU/MICROSOFT MACRO REMEDIATION
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way using `awk`:

```
awk -F ";" '{ a = $0; sub(/^\\\\[^\\]*\\[^\\]*/,""); gsub(/\\/,"/",$1); print a $1 }' file
```

Or simplifying the regex:

```
awk -F ";" '{ a = $0; sub(/^\\(\\[^\\]*){2}/,""); gsub(/\\/,"/",$1); print a $1 }' file
```

Results:

```
\\FILE09\12GAGE\LOAN CLOSING UNIT;\\FILE09\12GAGE;/fs8_100X/FILE09/bu/12gage/LOAN CLOSING UNIT
\\FILE44\FILE44\BU\EARPS\FUNDCHECK;\\FILE44\FILE44;/fs6_451B/FILE44/BU/EARPS/FUNDCHECK
\\FILE15\FILE15\BU\MICROSOFT MACRO REMEDIATION;\\FILE15\FILE15;/fs6_100X/FILE15/BU/MICROSOFT MACRO REMEDIATION
```

Answer (score 1):

Using sed:

```
sed -e 's/\(\([^\\]*\\\)\{4\}\)\([^;]*\);\(.*\)/\1\3;\4\/\3/' 
    -e ':l s/\([^;]*;[^;]*;[^\\]*\)\\/\1\//;t l' input
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 'h;s/^(([\\][^\\]*){3})([^;]*).*/\3/;y/\\/\//;H;g;s/\n//' file
```

- `h` copy the original line to the hold space (HS)
- `s/^(([\\][^\\]*){3})([^;]*).*/\3/` isolate the string in question
- `y/\\/\//` replace the `\`'s with `/`'s
- `H` append the amended string to the original line in the HS (introduces a newline)
- `g` retrieve the amended line into the pattern space (PS)
- `s/\n//` delete the newline

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F";" '{n=split($1,a,"\\");$0=$0"/"a[n];print $0}' your_file
```

tested below:

```
 cat temp
\\FILE09\12GAGE\LOAN CLOSING UNIT;\\FILE09\12GAGE;/fs8_100X/FILE09/bu/12gage
\\FILE44\FILE44\BU\EARPS\FUNDCHECK;\\FILE44\FILE44;/fs6_451B/FILE44
\\FILE15\FILE15\BU\MICROSOFT MACRO REMEDIATION;\\FILE15\FILE15;/fs6_100X/FILE15

> awk -F";" '{n=split($1,a,"\\");$0=$0"/"a[n];print $0}' temp
\\FILE09\12GAGE\LOAN CLOSING UNIT;\\FILE09\12GAGE;/fs8_100X/FILE09/bu/12gage/LOAN CLOSING UNIT
\\FILE44\FILE44\BU\EARPS\FUNDCHECK;\\FILE44\FILE44;/fs6_451B/FILE44/FUNDCHECK
\\FILE15\FILE15\BU\MICROSOFT MACRO REMEDIATION;\\FILE15\FILE15;/fs6_100X/FILE15/MICROSOFT MACRO REMEDIATION
>
```